# Titan by Stephen Baxter- why land in 3 vehicles?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, space-exploration, stephen-baxter

In *Titan* by Stephen Baxter, a heavily modified space shuttle with two capsules in its cargo bay lands on Titan, but the two capsules detach and land separately before the shuttle re-enters.

Since they need the shuttle's life support to survive, if it crashes they will die anyway. So why triple the risk by landing the two capsules? Indeed, this does end up killing an astronaut when one of the capsules doesn't land properly.

Baxter writes very hard sci-fi, so there must be an explanation I'm forgetting (I haven't read the book in many years).

Comment: I've never read the books, but is it possible that the shuttle would have been too heavy to land on Titan with them in the cargo bay? (And how can a shuttle **RE**-enter Titan's atmosphere if it has never been there before????)

Comment: Is that the one where they get an X-15 out of a museum and try to shoot down the shuttle? If so, don't look for authenticity.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's the one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mission was put together as quickly as possible, using as much old hardware as possible to reduce costs. In the planning meeting Rosenberg came up with the plan to get the hab down to the surface of Titan:

> Titan has a thick atmosphere, and a low gravity. You'd *glide* the hab
> module down, inside your Shuttle orbiter. Which is why you'd take the
> orbiter. The aerosurfaces would need some modification, but…

The logical thing would be for the astronauts to descend in the orbiter too, but there would not be enough time available to develop a "man-rated system", that is, a way of bringing the shuttle down that would pass NASA safety checks. The alternative was to send the shuttle down unmanned, and drop the astronauts in simple entry capsules which were available and already man-rated:

> Maybe you're right, Rosenberg. Maybe you could do that quickly and
> cheaply. But not if you wanted a man-rated system.
>
> "Send the orbiter down to Titan unmanned," Rosenberg said. Then it can
> land as hard as you like."
>
> "And what about the crew?" Angel said.
>
> "All you need is a couple of simple man-rated entry capsules,"
> Rosenberg said. "Remember, we aren't talking about any kind of
> ascent-to-orbit capability; it's a one-way trip."

There would be sufficient room in one capsule to fit all four of the astronauts. But this was vetoed, on the grounds that if the capsule made a bad landing, the whole crew would be lost.

> "We could all four of us ride down in the one capsule. It wouldn't be
> comfortable, but with a couch installed in the lower equipment bay—"
>
> "Again, bad idea," Rosenberg said. "We ought to go down separately. If
> one Apollo has a bad landing, we only hurt half the crew; the rest are
> on hand to help."

So the three-way split was so that the shuttle could land unmanned, and the two capsules would give some redundancy to the crewed part of the mission.

Comment: I guess that makes sense because the shuttle could not burn up but still land too roughly for humans to survive and equipment could still be scavenged from the wreck